# 1064 SQL error - don't know how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I try to upload my SQL file to PHPMyAdmin I receive this error.

```
SQL query: Dumping data for table data

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123'),
;

MySQL said: Documentation
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

phpMyAdmin SQL Dump

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `datasorter`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `data`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `data` (
`id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`dt` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`console` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`age` varchar(1000) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `data`
--

INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123'),
;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Comment: Is this file dumped by `mysqldump`? I wonder why `mysqldump` generated wrong INSERT statement.

BTW, when I execute this file, syntax error occurs at line number 2. but you got an error at line 6.

Comment: Oh yer thanks guys! Now however I'm receiving #1054 - Unknown column 'console' in 'field list' error?

Answer (score 2):

Remove comma before semicolon:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123'),
;
```

Should be:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/506f10/1/0)**</kbd>

Storing `dt` as `VARCHAR` is very bad practice. Consider using proper datatype.

`Age` shoud be calculated/generated column unless you want to update it every year.

Comment: Oh yer thanks guys! Now however I'm receiving #1054 - Unknown column 'console' in 'field list' error?

Answer (score 0):

remove the comma after `'age')`

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES (1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of your query :

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123'),;
                                     ^^
                                     Here
```

Just change it to this :

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `name`, `dt`, `console`, `age`) VALUES
(1, 'abc', '1/june/2015', 'abc','123');
```